# How to invite friends in windows 8 facebook app?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-8

I'm porting Unity3D game to windows 8. And it's use a facebook requests to invite friends. I tried to use facebook C# sdk to send invites via facebook graph api:

```
dynamic id = await client.PostTaskAsync(String.Format("{0}/apprequests", friend.id), parameters);
```

but it only can send requests to users, which already have the game installed.
 Is it possible to send request or message to invite friends to my windows 8 game?
 And how did microsoft do it on the facebook for win 8 app?

Comment: Have you figured this out? i am stuck with the same problem.

Comment: Have a look at my answer that solved the issue for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23241080/2807590

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to open browser window (embedded WebView) and navigate to URI like https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?
  app_id=APP_ID&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response

Answer (score 0):

You can only send notifications programatically like this for users who have already installed and authorized your application. Imagine how much spam we would get if any application could send anyone a request! (*shudder*)

What you are referring to is an invite request. You want to allow your users to invite new users to your application. For this you need to use the request dialog. I haven't got any experience with win8 or with Unity, but the Facebook API is pretty consistent across platforms.

You can use this JS code to prompt your users with the request dialog and allow them to select the friends to invite.

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'My Great Request'
}, requestCallback);
```

Note that the only real difference is that I'm not specifying any user id's so Facebook simply displays the multi-friend selector dialog.

Reference - [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Comment: My problem is that i can't call this dialog from windows 8 app because there is no facebook sdk for windows 8. Did anybody know the way how can i call this dialog?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try with [this sdk](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/)? it is specific to windows 8 and windows phone.

Comment: yes, and it doesn't have that feature. That's basically what the question is about and the sample code in the question is from the sdk.