# Invite Facebook friends to mobile app that is not a game

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I have a mobile app (on WinPhone 8.1) that uses Facebook credentials for Azure authed login.

What I'm trying to do:

Provide users an organic way to invite facebook friends to use the app. Important to note, users gain no advantage by inviting friends, however it will enhance their experience as you can compare your progress in the app with the progress of friends (it is not a game).

Where I'm stuck:

I can't use the apprequests dialog, as it is not a game. I would like to use the 'send' dialog, but it is not available in mobile browsers. It is not a website, so using the POST publish API has no valid href to link (other than the app's download page, but that is not what the publish API is meant for).

What should I do?

Comment: It is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: Thanks for the reply. from Facebook "You may use the Message Dialog on iOS and Android, or the Send Dialog on Web. These products let a person send a message directly to their friends containing a link to your app.". My app is a 'web' app in accordance with azure-mobile-service specificiations, but the Send dialog does not work on mobile browsers. So i cannot use this.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067358/is-facebook-user-to-user-request-possible-with-w8-wp8-c-sharp-sdk/23241080#23241080) explains how to do it.
Otherwise, I would suggest you to market your app like a game, a bit of [gamification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification) should not hurt ! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the confounding variable is  the azure-mobile-service integration I'm using. This forces me to setup the facebook-app (in the Facebook dashboard) as a website (linked to myapp.azure.net). When a user hits the apprequest link, they are automatically redirected to azure-page. I need to be able to override this behavior, or use some other service that doesn't have the implicit link system.