# Facebook SDK capabilities WP8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I am integrating facebook in WP8 app for login,Post on wall(Share),Invite friends.

Here I am using Facebook [SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk) for .Net

Using SDK's capabilities I am able to do login using In app browser, Post on wall(Share).

I user `me/taggable_friends` GRAPH API for getting friends list as `me/friends` returns only those friends who are using our app.

My app is not Game App so I can't use invitable friends API.

**My Question is: How to invite friend?**

If its not possible, Can anyone tell me the official list of possible things with facebook sdk on windows phone 8 except [this](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/).

**UPDATE**: I am able to send app request using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067358/is-facebook-user-to-user-request-possible-with-w8-wp8-c-sharp-sdk/23241080#23241080), but not seen any request came on receiver's facebook account.

Thanks,
Replies are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I used this method which works for me

Use a WebBrowser control and set the Url as

Uri inviteUri = new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id={app_id_goes_here}&message=YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE!&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/{app_id_goes_here}/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

From this you can search for your other friends who are not using the game yet.

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067358/is-facebook-user-to-user-request-possible-with-w8-wp8-c-sharp-sdk/23241080#23241080) seems like app request thing.Although I cant see the invitation on receiver's account. P.S. This app is not a game.